# How to send form field values in libcurl ? (the one that uses -F option in command line curl)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have some curl commands that uses -F option to send. for e.g:-F key=value -F policy=value. These would need to be sent now with libcurl and c++. I tried sending it as json payload, but that did not work as expected. Gives the error "bad request". I googled for the mapping of -F option to libcurl, but could not find. Any pointers would help.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you need to do. Let's see some code, and explain exactly how you want to invoke the curl (or libcurl API?). Reference: https://ec.haxx.se/http-postvspost.html As for how libcurl works, there are guides out there for how to do various POST requests with libcurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Multi part file data is the way to send the information with the following format: "name" "value" or "key" "Value"